# How to set maxlength property to each string entered with commas in one input field

Tags: html, angular

I have an input textbox field where a user can enter comma separated values like...

```
value 1,value 2,value 3,value 4
```

I have a requirement to set the maximum length of each value entered in that field to be 128 characters. I know we have a `maxlength` property which will set at overall field level. But is there any way which I can restrict the length of each value that is being entered in the field?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="licenseOwnerName" maxlength="128">
```

Above HTML will set for the total value in the field, but How can I set for each value separated by comma.

I have a validator which checks whether the user entered at least 2 values

```
    import { AbstractControl } from "@angular/forms";

    export function InputValuesValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
        if (control.value) {
            let splitString = (control.value).split(',');
            if(splitString.length == 1 || splitString[1] == "") {
                return { 'valuelisterror': true };
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Can I modify this validator to check for length as well? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: design a custom validation function for your requirement, let me know if you need help in writing one I can help

Comment: Hi Deepak, yes please, it would be great if you can help me doing that. Thanks

Comment: You need to evaluate if the entered value is 128 chars between commas or before comma?

Answer (score 0):

make your text validation function be like this,

```
textInputValidation(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const valuesLength = control.value.split(',').length - 1;
    if (control.value.split(',')[valuesLength].length>128) {
      return {
        textLengthError: 'You have entered more than 128 chars '
      };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
}
```

You will also have to remove `maxlength` property from your HTML, also my suggestion is that use different functions for validation, putting all the validation logic is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

It's important when you try to make some component, first try to create a simple model of it, for what you want it's much better if you try to do that:

> `event.keyCode === 188` mean comma, also you can add Enter or whatever you want; and the *input always has a maxlength and user can't type more than it*

[image]

Html:

```
<label for="tag" class="a">
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let tag of tags">{{tag}}</li>
<li>
  <input id="tag" type="text" maxlength="125" [(ngModel)]="tag" (keyup)="callMe($event)">
</li>
</ul>
</label>
```

ts:

```
tags = [];
tag = null;

callMe(event) {
  if (this.tag.length <= 128) {
    if (event.keyCode === 188) {
      this.tags.push(this.tag);
      this.tag = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Css:

```
.a {
 border: dashed 1px #ccc;
 display: block;
}

.a ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 5px;
 list-style: none;
}

input {
 border: none;
 outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This creates an array of words seperated by a comma and checks them for a length (4 here). Just a rough idea, customize it to your needs.

```
<input id="license" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="licenseOwnerName" maxlength="128">
```

```
let lic = document.getElementById("license");
lic.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  lic_arr = lic.value.split(",");
    for(let word in lic_arr) {
    if(lic_arr[word].length > 4) {
      alert("too long");
    }
  }
})
```